# Web worker file is cached and never re-loaded in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, caching, web-worker

I am running a simple HTML5 app that works in Chrome and Firefox. It uses a web worker, as in:

```
var worker = new Worker("the/worker/URL/Code.js");
```

I have experimented for over an hour in IE, and I finally found that the web worker's code is never reloaded. When I get the version that it has, to throw an error, the debugger shows me a completely outdated version of the worker code file, even though, all other files have been reloaded properly.

I flushed the cache, using the standard advice found everywhere: Safety -> Delete Browsing History -> Select items -> Ok -> Wait -> Ctrl+F5 to reload -> BAM, thee debugger still shows 100% the same file as several hours ago (remember that reloading works as expected in Chrome and FF).

When I look at the Network profiler, I see:

```
URL Protocol    Method  Result  Type    Received    Taken   Initiator   Wait‎‎  Start‎‎ Request‎‎   Response‎‎  Cache read‎‎    Gap‎‎
/js/core/WorkerScriptCode.js    (Pending...)    GET (Pending...)    (Pending...)    0 B (Pending...)    webworker   1311    0   0   0   0   31
```

I don't know why it says "Pending"; I can see that the worker already runs: I can see the work of the worker being done (e.g. the `importScripts` calls show up, and there are also above mentioned stacktraces). But it simply runs a completely outdated version, even though I flushed the entire cache tens of times.

Is this an uber-bug, or am I being stupid?

Comment: I suggest you the same I suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455743/web-worker-wont-start-in-ie-unless-the-cache-is-cleared):
It can be the http headers of the response. (specially cache control, expires, etag and last-modified) I suggest you  to take a look to the http headers in the network panel in developer tools [network panel](http://i.imgur.com/HI9HkL4.png) and share it us. May be you'll realize the problem right away.

Comment: @JohannEchavarria I am getting 304. So for some reason it just aggressively caches that baby. Question remains: How could a cache flush not fix this?

Comment: 304 is just the status code of the response request. The reason it caches that baby is probably the http headers. Please open F12 > network panel > select the webworker url > click in the details tab > Select response headers > take a picture and share it here. Some http headers related with cache are:
cache control, expires, etag and last-modified.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem exists in Chrome.  In order to get around it you can use a cache buster:

Main Code:

```
var buster = randomNumberOrBuildNumber;
var worker = new Worker( "the/worker/URL/Code.js?buster=" + buster );
```

Worker:

```
importScripts( 'script/to/import.js' + self.location.search );
```

This will apply `?buster=12345` (or whatever your `randomNumberOrBuildNumber` is set to) to both the loading of the worker and any `importScripts()` calls the worker makes.

Comment: Hard reload used to work for me in Chrome and FireFox though (in Chrome, make sure to open the development tools, then right-click the reload icon -> "Hard reload")

Comment: I've been using Cmd+Shift+R (MacBook Pro) for a "hard reload", but it still caches the imported scripts.  It might be that going through the menus works to reload, but when you're actually *developing* one of the imported scripts, going through menus to reload the page to test something is a huge drain on workflow.

Comment: I don't know why Chrome does not have a shortcut key for the "Clear cache and reload page"... but it's not that hard to get to that either, just 2 clicks :)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to enable "Always refresh from server" on the network tab. After I enabled it and refreshed the page, the worker was updated every time I edited it.

[Always refresh from server enabling in IE network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQEpj.png)